# Is there a way to whitelist email attachments with Tika?

Tags: java, apache-tika

Is there a way to whitelist some extensions while reading email attachments with Tika? For example, I only want to read attachments with the following extensions: .doc, .docx, .pdf. Can someone provide any example?

Thank you

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? Java code? If so, what code? Tika App runnable jar? Tika Server jar? Other?

Comment: Hey @Gagravarr I'm using on AWS lambdas, just creating a new instance of Tika and calling parseToString from there. I know I can use tika-config.xml, but I couldn't figure out how to create a whitelist on it.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think you'd need to stop using the `Tika` facade class, call the parser directly (probably `AutoDetectParser`), and pop a [EmbeddedDocumentExtractor](https://tika.apache.org/1.24/api/org/apache/tika/extractor/EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.html) on the `ParseContext` to pick what to recurse into from there. Changing `tika-config.xml` would apply across all formats, not just email

Comment: Thank you @Gagravarr. In my case, I would like to whitelist both, regular files and .eml/.msg attachments. Do you have any example? Thank you again.

Comment: If you want to prevent most file types being processed, whether files or attachments, and only do a handful, simplest way is `tika-config.xml` where you just list the parsers for the formats you actually want, see https://tika.apache.org/1.24/configuring.html